# How can I see if a variable such as a lag in a stata regression for a GARCH/ARCH model is statistically significant?

Tags: statistical-significance, stata, garch

[image]

If I was to look at data such as what I have posted here, how would I interpret it to model arch or garch. Which lags would be statistically significant and how does the datatset show this.

Comment: You can just look at the p-value in the output (P>|z|). Only the lagged variance seems to be significant. Try to estimate a GARCH(1,1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a GARCH(5,1) model with 5 "ARCH" lags (lags of squared residuals) and 1 "GARCH" lag (lag of conditional variance).

You can assess statistical significance by looking at $p$-values in the column `P>|z|` and comparing values there with a chosen significance level, e.g. 10%, 5% or 1% (0.10, 0.05 or 0.01). $p$-values below significance level indicate statistically significant lags, while those above indicate not statistically significant lags.

At a the conventional 10%, 5% and 1% significance levels, only the "GARCH" lag is significant, since its $p$-value (column `P>|z|`) is below 1%. The p-values for "ARCH" lags are all above 10%, thus insignificant.